# How to recieve live stream from IP camera using opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, ip-camera

I am building a project wherein I capture video from webcam or usb camera or from url and perform object detection on the video using machine learning tensorflow API. Everything works fine if I take the input video from webcam or external usb camera but when I take input from IP camera using url the code fails after running for 30-40 seconds.
My code looks like this

```
import cv2
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(“rtsp://x.xx.xx.xx:554”) 
While(True) 
  _,img = vid.read()
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  final_img = show_inference(detection_model , img)

  final_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

  cv2.imshow(‘frame’, final_img)
  If cv2.waitkey(1)
    break
Vid.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This works fine when i execute it with webcam or usb camera using below lines:

`cv2.VideoCapture(0)` or `cv2.VideoCapture(1)`

But when i run using url it shows me frame for 30-40 seconds and then fails with the below error

```
OpenCV(4.4.0)\source\color.cpp:182: error:(-215:Asertion failed)!_src.empty() in function ‘cv::cvtColor’
```

It appears to me that the opencv library fails to capture live feed from url and then the code fails.
Anyone any idea how to resolve this issue, below are the versions and specifications i am using:

- Using Tensorflow 2.0 on i5 machine without gpu
- Hikvision PTZ IP camera
- Python version 3.7
- Opencv version 4.4

Answer (score 1):

code:

- check vid.isOpened(). if it isn't, do not read.
- say `rv, img = vid.read()`
- check that rv is True, otherwise break loop

are you throttling the reception of frames *in any way*? does your inference step take much time?

set the camera to a lower FPS value. the camera will produce frames at its own rate. it will not stop or slow down for you.

when you don't read frames, they queue up. they do not disappear. that will eventually cause you to crash or give you other types of failure. you absolutely must consume frames as fast as they are made.

Comment: I am not throttling the frames in any way as of now. Yes my inference step takes longer time. But the code always works properly with webcam and inference step takes longer time while using webcam also. Can you suggest some ways how to catch frames at the required rate or to match recieving rate with reading rate. Can multithreading help here?

Comment: the driver for the webcam may be more forgiving than the code handling the network stream. yes multithreading can help, if you do it right. start a thread that continuously reads frames and keeps the most recent frame around. any consumers read that frame when they need to. use python's Condition object to notify consumers of new frames.

Comment: use this, modify as needed. https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40

Comment: The ip camera driver and propriety software has been of no help. I will definately try multithreading. Also i tried opening the same url with opencv without using any machine learning algo, it worked fine. Which brings me to conclusion that i need to find a way that machine learning on the IP stream becomes faster. Any idea about that?

Comment: that exceeds the scope of this question. use my gist linked earlier to work around the frame rate issue.

Comment: I am on it. Thanks :-)